# How to perform this induction properly?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, induction

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f$ continuously differentiable $n$ times on $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon >0$, there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that for all $i=0\dots n$: $$||f^{(i)}-p^{(i)}||<\epsilon$$

I have proven that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on $[a,b]$ then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ s.t.  $||F-p||_\infty , ||f-p'|| < \epsilon$ (*).

Now I want to induct on $i$ to prove the claim above, but I'm struggling to do this properly. I tried inducting from $n$ back to $0$ in order to be able to define $f^{(i-1)}$ as the antiderivative of $f^{(i)}$ but I'm struggling to 'pull back' $p$ since it has to originate from the same $p$ used in the base case $i=n$. How can I perform this induction properly so that I don't use a new $p$ each time I roll back using the pair in my earlier claim (denoted (*))?

**Edit: I'm adding here my full proof as it is:**

From (*) (using $f^{(n)}$ instead of $f$) we know that there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $||f^{(n-1)}-P_1||_\infty,||f^{(n)}-p||_\infty < \epsilon$ and $P_1'=p$.

For $f^{(n-2)}$ we can define $P_2$ from $P_1$ in the same way we have defined $p$ from $p'$ in (*), i.e. such that if $||f^{(n-1)}-P_1||_\infty < \epsilon$ then $||f^{(n-2)}-P_2||_\infty < \epsilon$ and $P_2'=P_1$.

Assume we have defined $f^{(1)}$ and $P_{n-1}$ in this way. Then we can define $f^{(0)}$ and $P_n$ in the same way, i.e. such that if $||f^{(1)}-P_{n-1}||_\infty < \epsilon$ then $||f^{(0)}-P_n||_\infty < \epsilon$ and $P_n'=P_{n-1}$.

Any comments / corrections etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass theorem ?

Comment: Stone-Weirstrass (SW) for polynomial approximation? Yes - but I have used it inside my claim (*) and so was thinking I could roll back the induction based on that claim. Do you think I have to re-use SW?

Comment: $f^{(i)}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ for all $i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$ since $f$ is $n$ times differentiable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: You use (*) with $f^{(n)}$, which is not necessarily continuous !

Comment: @SacAndSac OK, I double checked and indeed $f$ is **continuously** differentiable $n$(apologies - now fixing the question). Although this makes me wonder now whether the this addition is indeed required.